# The chain rule for Calculus in its expanded form

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am currently experiencing some difficulty with the chain rule and there is a debate in my introductory class with a fellow student about the correct way to express it in its expanded form.

[image]

Comment: In might help you receive positive/constructive feedback sooner if you provide specific details to explain your confusion. Please include details using proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's explained pretty thoroughly in the link.

Comment: please add your image@user3810748

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have the right idea. Let me try to give an explanation that will hopefully help out.

The chain rule is much clearer when written in Leibniz notation. Consider a function $f$ which depends on another function $g$, which itself depends on a variable $x$. (i.e. we have $f(g)$ and $g(x)$). Then the chain rule states:

$$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx} $$

In this form you can clearly see that the derivative of $f$ is taken with respect to $g$. It is not taken with respect to $x$. If you knew the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ then you wouldn't need the chain rule in the first place.

EDIT: Some clarification based off of comments. The distinction between $\frac{df}{dg}$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ is more than just semantics. These are completely different things. Often the chain rule is written as:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x) $$

The understanding is that when you place the prime it means 'derivative with respect to the argument.' This causes confusion sometimes because this notation is not explicit about what variable the derivative is in respect to. Note, however, that it is impossible for $f'(g(x))$ to mean $\frac{dg}{dx}$ in the context of the chain rule, because $\frac{dg}{dx}$ is precisely what you are trying to find. It is the element on the left hand side of the equation. If $f'(g(x))$ is taken to mean $\frac{df}{dx}$ then the chain rule says $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx} \frac{dg}{dx}$, implying that $\frac{dg}{dx}=1$. This issue is clearly not just a semantical difference. It produces the wrong result.

Comment: so Im guessing that the whole confusion stems from f(g(x))' ?

like the other guys are interpreting f(g(x)) as some compound that still revolves around x, e.g. f(g(x)) = (x^2)^2 and as such, f(g(x))' = f(g(x))'g(x)' which works out 2(x^2)(2x)

as opposed to us interpreting g(x) as another parameter of its own? So all this is essentially semantics then? and I have nothing to fear?

Comment: I would disagree that it is just semantics. $\frac{df}{dx}$ is not the same as $\frac{df}{dg}$. When you say $f(g(x))'=f(g(x))'g(x)'=2(x^2)(2x)$ you are carrying out the operation $\frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$. If it was really true that f'(g(x)) means $\frac{df}{dx}$ then the chain rule is nonsense, because it would imply $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx} \frac{dg}{dx}$, you can cancel the $\frac{df}{dx}$ from both sides and you get the result $1=\frac{dg}{dx}$

Comment: By the way, it is very confusing to write $f(g(x))'=f(g(x))'g(x)'$ because it looks like you have the same element $f(g(x))'$ on both the left and right of the equation when in the chain rule they are really not the same element at all.

Comment: Also, you mentioned trying to conceptualize this for multivariable functions, and I notice you are using the notation for partial derivatives in your examples in the link. All of this discussion is for the single variable case. The chain rule generalizes to multivariable functions, but the generalization is not obvious (at least not to me), and the formula is different than what we are discussing. Unless I'm misunderstanding your examples, you are only working with single variable functions and so you are not taking partial derivatives.

Comment: I'm actually not a fan of this way of stating the chain rule, because two different functions are both given the name $f$.  Different functions should have different names.

Comment: nice................+1

Comment: @littleO Fair enough. I can understand that reasoning.

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule states that if $h = f \circ g$ then
\begin{equation}
\tag{$\spadesuit$} h'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)
\end{equation}
(assuming $g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$).

Note that the number $g(x)$ is plugged into the function $f'$, and then we multiply by $g'(x)$.